# iOS iPad start landscape, push VC, popVC, view has bad positioning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I start my app in landscape for iPad.  A nav controller holds my tableVC  I click on a cell we push a new VC onto the stack.  That works fine.  The problem is, when I press the standard "back" button on the nav controller, my app gets forced into portrait and my tableVC is off of the screen.  I am doing no manual positioning of views. This doesn't happen if I start the app in portrait mode.

How do I fix this abnormal behavior?

Notes:  There is also a tab bar present in the app if it matters.

Upon further testing, if I load the NavController in portrait (with the first view being the table view) then switch it to landscape, then select the cell, then press back, it works fine. So the problem only happens if i start the app in landscape and never turn it to portrait.

EVERY VC has shouldAutoRotate set to return YES.  I have subclassed the tab bar and done the same.  I am wondering if this is a bug.  Perhaps the problem lies in the fact that I took existing .XIB files and their views that were created for iPhone, then copied and pasted them, then deleted the iPhone specific views and then added iPad views.

Comment: Have you implemented shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in each of the view controllers?

Comment: every VC in my app has that implemented and returns yes.  Is there something specific i need to do with the NavController?

Comment: ALL view controllers must support the rotation.  Including the tab controller, which is very likely the source of the problem.

Comment: i have subclassed the tab bar controller and the shouldautorotate and have that return yes (this was already implemented) and it still forces the screen into portrait when i pop the vc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can create a new and simple iPad application with just a tabbarcontroller a navigation controller and 2 viewcontrollers to test if the cause is or is not the recycled iPhone .XIB files.

Also you can Command+Shift+F to search in the whole project for ": UIViewController" to double check that every VC has shouldAutoRotate set to return YES, in case you have third party code in your application that has a subclass of UIViewController on it. (the search will return a list of headers files that inherits from UIViewController).

I had had similar problems with really weird behaviors that were fixed by deleting the .XIB file and made it again.

Good luck finding the problem =)

Comment: So I just did what you did, and delete the XIB files and recreate them. Apparently it was an XCode bug. Rule of thumb, don't convert iPhone XIB files to iPad

Answer (score 1):

If your subclassed TabBar Controller returns yes, and ALL of your VCs return yes for shouldAutoRotate, then the problem lies within your xib files. Though your explanation makes it sound like the VC you are pushing doesn't return yes, you've stated that it does, so it must be the xib files.

In IB, try setting the default orientation of your xib views to landscape, clean - build and run.

That may provide a clue or two.

Comment: You should make sure all your view's have the "autoresizes subviews" property checked, too.